# Error type 3 - Activity class does not exist

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm trying to run webRTC application but the error below returned:

> Launching application:
>   com.onlinevoicecallapp/com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity.
>
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n
>   "com.onlinevoicecallapp/com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.onlinevoicecallapp/.MainActivity }
>
> Error type 3 
>   Error:
>   Activity class
>   {com.onlinevoicecallapp/com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity} does not
>   exist.

When I searched for it I found many solutions but none of them works in my case, please advice!

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- WebRTC Dependencies -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<!-- PubNub Dependencies -->
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pubrtc"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.onlinevoicecallapp.VideoChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_video_chat"
        android:parentActivityName="com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.onlinevoicecallapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.onlinevoicecallapp.IncomingCallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_incoming_call">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.onlinevoicecallapp.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I found that this problem happens not only for webRTC, but also for every project I create!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discover that there was something wrong with the android studio, I haven't found the root cause of the problem yet, but the problem was fixed by uninstalling the android studio and install it from another source.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if you do not have a root cause?

Comment: Because it fixed the problem. I couldn't find help to know the root cause but this is the only thing that works.

Comment: Because it fixed the problem. I couldn't find help to know the root cause but this is the only thing that works.

Comment: The root cause in my case was proguard and multidex, on slower devices. Android could not access the segment the multidex put it in fast enough, causing this weird issue.

Comment: Could've been proguard, or even changing Edit Configurations->General->Deploy->Default Activity (or to Nothing depending on your gradle setup).

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this after manually uninstalling an old debug build. The app somehow got into a strange state where it was still installed, but "installed for another user". I had tried doing a clean build with no luck. This finally fixed it for me:

1. Go into the application list and find the app. For me it was "installed for other users".
2. Select "uninstall for all users" from the top-right menu.

After doing this I was able to deploy debug builds to the phone normally.

Comment: My hero! This fixed it for me. I wish i had found this before i pulled my hair out though...

Comment: This is the right answer thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I think the problem is you have already the same app under the different user which can be deleted by going to

- Setting > All Apps > Your App > Uninstall for all user

If the problem still persists you should try it from ADB itself to uninstall it with command on your terminal.

```
adb uninstall yourpackagename
```

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution was  go to **Gradle > Tasks > Install > UninstallAll**

Comment: Thank you! You saved me

Comment: This should be market as the correct answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an old version of the app wasn't uninstalled correctly.

When I uninstalled an app from the *launcher* on my LG G5, it still existed in >Settings>Apps but marked with "Deactivated".

I did have to uninstall it from >Settings>Apps to really delete it.
Afterwards I was able to install and run the app again.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing worked for me is, I changed the testing device from LG to Samsung and it started working for me. The same issue is observed more often on LG devices than any other devices.

Comment: Indeed, installed new device and it's working. I suppose an emulator becomes corrupt then this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this same error. This occurs to me when I moved launcher activity to some other folder.

But Internally Android studio was looking file at previous path.

I cleaned the project many time, but error was still there.Finally Just by doing one step error is gone.

**I solved this error by restarting Android Studio and opening project again.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tried almost all solutions given above. The error was still there. Then I just restarted the Emulator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**In my case the emulator was in safe mode**

> restart the emulator and voila.
> NB restart to remove it from safe mode

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem.
Go to **Run** -> **Edit Configuration**-> and then check **Install for all users** checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First try
adb uninstall com.packagename
working fine for me

if it not working try

1. Clean build
2. Simply refactor and rename project package name
3. Go to android app list
4. Find for the app
5. Uninstall for all users

Answer (score 0):

**Your device contains the old version of the apk**. You might be renamed the package or changed the app identifier. So, when you are installing new version of the apk then it won't install due to package mismatch.
To resolve that issue,

- Uninstall old version of the apk from your device.
- If still the issue persists then clean the project by selecting `Build --> Clean Project` in Android studio.

Answer (score -1):

May you have installed the app in your android ,try to uninstall it by adb commend
"adb uninstall com.onlinevoicecallapp"

Comment: needs some editing to make the statement clear - not very understandable right now