# Error type 3 - Error while Launching activity

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

It works fine in nougat and below. But gives `Error type 3` - Error while Launching activity in `Oreo`. How can I fix it?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zzz.com.z">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LiveTrack"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_live_track"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".YourActivityRunOnStartup"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".ShutDownReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zzz.com.z"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.01"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error:

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.zzz.com.z/com.zzz.com.z.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.zzz.com.z/.MainActivity
>   } Error type 3 Error: Activity class
>   {com.zzz.com.z/com.zzz.com.z.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity

Comment: Did you try the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20915266? Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/41909487, or https://stackoverflow.com/q/19670607.

Comment: Clean the project, delete the build directory from root and app folder , restart android studio, rebuild and run.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem.. It works fine in nougat and marshmallow devices but the problem exists only in oreo

Comment: your package name is "com.zzz.com.z"; a more standard package name would be "com.zzz.com"

Comment: Will that cause the problem?

Comment: When I install the app directly from android studio, the above error occurs, when I build the signed apk and install, it gives app not installed error but the debugged apk works fine.. what may be the reason? It happens only in oreo, all apk works fine in nougat and below it

Comment: I have answered this question in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58229193/7776322). I hope i works for you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be in your Manifest file. Check **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Check the presence of those intent-filters inside your Activity declaration. Like below.

```
<activity
     android:name=".main.SplashScreenActivity"       
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

If this information is there, maybe some cache problem occurred. Then, try this:

> Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...